# Why does C-u C-c C-c place the vsum() in current row of an org-mode table instead of the row mentioned in #+TBLFM?

Tags: org-mode, org-table, formula

I have this org-mode table in a file named `1.org`:

```
| . |  A |   B |    C |
|---+----+-----+------|
| X | 10 | 100 | 1000 |
| Y | 20 | 200 | 2000 |
| Z | 30 | 300 | 3000 |
|---+----+-----+------|
| T |    |     |      |
#+TBLFM: @5$2..$4=vsum(@I..@II)
```

If I move the cursor to the `#+TBLFM` line and run `C-c C-c`, I get the totals of each column in the last row labelled `T` like so

```
| . |  A |   B |    C |
|---+----+-----+------|
| X | 10 | 100 | 1000 |
| Y | 20 | 200 | 2000 |
| Z | 30 | 300 | 3000 |
|---+----+-----+------|
| T | 60 | 600 | 6000 |
#+TBLFM: @5$2..$4=vsum(@I..@II)
```

All good so far. But if instead I place the cursor on the row labelled `Y` (for example, just place the cursor on `Y`) and then run `C-u C-c C-c` I get this

```
| . |   A |    B |     C |
|---+-----+------+-------|
| X |  10 |  100 |  1000 |
| Y |  60 |  600 |  6000 |
| Z | 100 | 1000 | 10000 |
|---+-----+------+-------|
| T | 170 | 1700 | 17000 |
#+TBLFM: @5$2..$4=vsum(@I..@II)
```

Why did it place the sum of each column in the row labelled `Y` even though the the `#+TBLFM` clearly says to put the sum in last row (row `@5`)?

---

Documentation of `C-u C-c C-c` - https://orgmode.org/manual/Updating-the-table.html

> `C-u C-c *` or `C-u C-c C-c`
>
> Recompute the entire table, line by line. Any lines before the first hline are left alone, assuming that these are part of the table header.

Comment: Good question and very much a bug I'm afraid (and a serious one at that). Please report it ASAP with `M-x org-submit-bug-report`.

Comment: AFAICT, this (mis)behavior goes back a long way: at least back to 8.3.

Comment: I have looked at this issue by enabling the debugger. org-table-toggle-formula-debugger is on C-c {, <menu-bar> <table> <Debug Formulas>.  The problem is cursor IS NOT STARTING on a table cell that has a formula.  It starts on a table cell that has  a value.  The issue is one of seeking the right cell, before doing eval.    It seems to start on a cell on where the cursor is.    Or it could be that inserts the calculated value in the wrong cell.  (The problem actually seems a combination of both).  May be this is problem could be isolated to a commit using a git bisect.